# call endpoint in a controlled loop

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following use case: I use Camel as a webservice proxy, I get request from A, enrich the SOAP Headers and forward to B. The response of B gets back to A. (I replaced the actual product names with A & B)

My route looks like this:

```
    <route id="orderLimitRoute">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:aOrderLimit?dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE" />
        <to uri="bean:soapHeadersEnricher"/>
        <to uri="cxf:bean:bOrderLimit?dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE" />
    </route>
```

The route like this works, that's not the problem.

The enricher retrieves an accesskey from somewhere, and puts in the SOAP Header. B only accepts requests with a valid accesskey. Retrieving an acceskey is an expensive operation so we use a pool for this, also B doesn't really define when an accesskey gets invalid. So we have this (in non-Camel scenario's):

```
public Object execute(Call call) throws AbstractBWebServiceException {
    Object result = null;
    AccessKey accessKey = null;
    int tries = maxTries > 0 ? maxTries : accessKeyPool.getMaxActive() + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < tries && accessKey == null; i++) {
        try {
            accessKey = borrowAccessKey();
            result = call.execute(accessKey);
        } catch (BWebServiceLoginException loginException) {
            invalidate(accessKey);
            accessKey = null;
        } finally {
            if (accessKey != null) {
                returnAccessKey(accessKey);
            }
        }
    }

    if (accessKey == null) {
        throw new BWebServiceAccessKeyException("Couldn't get a valid accesskey");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Where call.execute(accessKey) does the call to B. Now I would like to use that piece of Java code in my Camel route. Either directly, or translated into Camel logic. But I have no clue how to do this, I looked at the Camel documentation over and over but can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it, 'soapHeadersEnricher' is a bean which inserts the accesskey into the soapheader, and also puts it on the exchange. When the accesskey is deemed invalid I get a SOAPFault with a specific code in it. 'bLoginExceptionPredicate' checks for that specific code, and redelivery is enabled for that type of exception. The 'onRedelivery' gets the invalid accesskey from the exchange, marks it invalid for the pool, requests a new one, sets it on the exchange and in the SOAP header. The final processor returns the accesskey to the pool.

```
from("cxf:bean:brokerOrderLimit?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&allowStreaming=false")
            .process(soapHeadersEnricher)
            .onException(SoapFault.class)
            .onWhen(bLoginExceptionPredicate)
            .handled(false) // return fault to client
            .maximumRedeliveries(2)
            .redeliveryDelay(5000) 
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            .logHandled(false)
            .onRedelivery(soapHeadersEnricher)
            .end()
            .to("cxf:bean:bOrderLimit?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&allowStreaming=false")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    AccessKey accessKey = exchange.getProperty(BSoapHeadersEnricher.ACCESKEY_PROPERTY, AccessKey.class);
                    accessKeyProvider.returnAccessKey(accessKey);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

From Java code, you can use the ProducerTemplate to send a message to any Camel endpoints.
http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html

Comment: I almost solved it using redeliveries and error handling, but encountered VERY strange errors with redelivery only working when putting camel logging on DEBUG: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/need-help-with-error-handling-td5730399.html